# How to disable Submit button if nothing is selected in Primefaces SelectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:selectOneMenu` whose first element is a string 'Please select' and other items are a list to be selected. Can I disable the submit button when 'Please select' is selected and enable the button if other elements are selected? I know that `itemDisabled` can be used, but that is not my requirement.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.value}" id="selectId"
    filter="true" required="true" converter="itemConverter"
    filterMatchMode="contains" height="120">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{listBean.selectItemList}"></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Essentially, I want the submit button to be disabled when the first item is selected.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You better replace

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select"/>
```

With

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Please select"></f:selectItem>
```

And let the jsf to handle the `required` for you...

---

If you really want to disable the button just use the `#{bean.value}`

like this

```
<p:commandButton id="myButonId" disabled="#{empty bean.value}"....
```

and add `<p:ajax update="myButonId"` to your `<p:selectOneMenu`

Comment: Knew this solution, but just wanted to know if the button could be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Rajath, 
          Why cant you use a **SelectItemList** in the backing bean and add label and values to that list from backingbean ? The advantage of doing that is, you can add "please Select "as the first label in the SelectItemList and value as null. So for disabling SubmitButton you can have a **boolean flag** which can be set to true or false according to the values in SelectItemList( use a **valuechangeListener** and update the  boolean flag accordingly in that method ). Hope this solution will help you.

Comment: The disadvantage is that it clutters the model with something that's specific to the view. Having a default "Please select" item in the view keeps the model clean of view-specific clutter.